# No module named 'django.core.exception'

Tags: django

Current version of Python **3.7.3**. Recently I reinstalled and all the components of Django were already.
But such module does not work

```
from django.core.exception import ValidationError
```

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whPky.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get from that there is a module `django.core.exception`

It is [django.core.exceptions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/exceptions/)